# can't use strings instead of integers in area charts in morris charts library

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, morris.js

[Bar Chart Example](http://jsbin.com/uzosiq/258/embed?javascript,live)

```
Morris.Bar({
  element: 'bar-example',
  data: [
    { y: 'dddd', a: 100, b: 90 },
    { y: '2007', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2008', a: 50,  b: 40 },
    { y: '2009', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2010', a: 50,  b: 40 },
    { y: '2011', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2012', a: 100, b: 90 }
  ],
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
  labels: ['Series A', 'Series B']
});
```

[Area Chart Example](http://jsbin.com/otaxef/115/embed?javascript,live)

```
Morris.Area({
  element: 'area-example',
  data: [
    { y: 'dddd', a: 100, b: 90 },
    { y: '2007', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2008', a: 50,  b: 40 },
    { y: '2009', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2010', a: 50,  b: 40 },
    { y: '2011', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2012', a: 100, b: 90 }
  ],
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
  labels: ['Series A', 'Series B']
});
```

In Morris Chart library Bar charts accepts strings for Y-AXIS  but Area one doesn't.I can't understand  why ?

[THIS IS THE MORRIS LIBRARY](http://www.oesmith.co.uk/morris.js/bars.html)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Morris.js is trying to parse x-values as timestamp. But 'dddd' has invalid format. You can skip date parsing by using `parseTime: false` option ([jsbin](http://jsbin.com/EJOXujiG/1/edit?js,output)). In this case X values will be treated as an equally-spaced series.
[See docs](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/lines.html)